# DockerCompose operation mismatched

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There are two docker-compose containers in one server which have different `container_name` and `hostname`. When I enter one container path and run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml stop && docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d` command, the other container will follow the command and restart.

[image]

Container One's `docker-compose.dev.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: sycamore
services:
  backend:
    container_name: sycamore-research-backend-dev
    hostname: sycamore-research-dev
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
      args:
        env: dev
    env_file:
      - backend.dev.env
    ports:
      - '9989:80'
    environment:
      ACCESS_LOG: ./logs/access.log
      ERROR_LOG: ./logs/error.log
    volumes:
      - './app:/app'
      - './upload:/upload'
    command: bash /start-reload.sh
    networks:
      - default
```

Container Two's `docker-compose.dev.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: sycamore
services:
  backend:
    container_name: sycamore-jsincubator-backend-dev
    hostname: sycamore-jsincubator-dev
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: backend.dockerfile
      args:
        env: dev
    env_file:
      - backend.dev.env
    ports:
      - '9500:80'
    environment:
      ACCESS_LOG: /mnt/development/mount/SycamoreJSIncubator/logs/access.log
      ERROR_LOG: /mnt/development/mount/SycamoreJSIncubator/logs/error.log
    volumes:
      - './app:/app'
    command: bash /start-reload.sh
    networks:
      - default
```

I have no idea totally why this happened. The two docker-compose containers have different `container_name` and `hostname`. The only same is their `networks`.

Versions:

- `docker`: `Docker version 19.03.11, build 42e35e61f3`
- `docker-compose`: `docker-compose version 1.26.0, build unknown`
- System: `CentOS 7`

Comment: Are both `docker-compose.dev.yml` files in directories with the same name?  (Something like `research/docker/docker-compose.dev.yml` and `incubator/docker/docker-compose.dev.yml`, say.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, there are in `research/backend/docker-compose.dev.yml` and `incubator/backend/docker-compose.dev.yml`.

Comment: Compose uses the `backend` directory name as its "project" name, and attaches that name to containers with Docker labels.  Since they're both the same "project", Compose wants to replace one set of containers with the other.  The `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable or `docker-compose -p` option can override this name.

Comment: @DavidMaze Yeah, it's the problem. Thanks a lot.